# Android - sqlite gridview lag

Tags: android, sqlite, gridview, android-sqlite

I have done research but couldn't find a clear explanation, I know it has been asked before but I still don't have a solution.

I have a gridView that gets populated by sqlite. The problem is that the scroll of my gridView has lags. My code--

---

Adapter;

```
public class FoodListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private  int layout;
private ArrayList<Food> foodsList;

public FoodListAdapter(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<Food> foodsList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.layout = layout;
    this.foodsList = foodsList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return foodsList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return foodsList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

private class ViewHolder{
    CircularImageView imageView;
    TextView txtName, txtPrice;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    View row = view;
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();


    if(row == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(layout, null);

        holder.txtName = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        holder.txtPrice = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
        holder.imageView = (CircularImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgFood);
        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    Food food = foodsList.get(position);

    holder.txtName.setText(food.getName());
    holder.txtPrice.setText(food.getPrice());

    byte[] foodImage = food.getImage();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(foodImage, 0, foodImage.length);
    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    return row;

}

}
```

---

Activity;

```
public class FoodList extends AppCompatActivity {

GridView gridView;
ArrayList<Food> list;
AdapterView adapterView;
FoodListAdapter adapter = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.student_list_activity);

    sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(this, "FoodDB.sqlite", null, 1);

    sqLiteHelper.queryData("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FOOD(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR, price VARCHAR, image BLOB)");

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new FoodListAdapter(this, R.layout.food_items, list);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            String dataFromGrid;
            dataFromGrid = ((TextView)(view.findViewById(R.id.txtName))).getText().toString();


            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FoodInfo.class);

            i.putExtra("unfromfood",dataFromGrid);
            startActivity(i);


        }
    });

    // get all data from sqlite
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT * FROM FOOD");
    list.clear();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        int id = cursor.getInt(0);
        String name = cursor.getString(1);
        String price = cursor.getString(2);
        byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(3);

        list.add(new Food(name, price, image, id));
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();




}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteHelper.getData("SELECT * FROM FOOD");
    list.clear();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        int id = cursor.getInt(0);
        String name = cursor.getString(1);
        String price = cursor.getString(2);
        byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(3);

        list.add(new Food(name, price, image, id));
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

//Creating The Options Menu
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

//Option Menu Click Events
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    // Settings
    if (id == R.id.action_add_student) {

        {
            final Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(Student.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    return true;
}

}
```

Everything works fine except the scrolling has lags, any help would be appreciated.

---

**EDIT**

```
public class AddFood extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText edtName, edtPrice;
Button btnChoose, btnAdd, btnList;
CircularImageView imageView;

final int REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY = 999;

public static SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_food);

    init();

    sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(this, "FoodDB.sqlite", null, 1);

    sqLiteHelper.queryData("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FOOD(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name VARCHAR, price VARCHAR, image BLOB)");

    btnChoose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    AddFood.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY
            );
        }
    });

    //THIS IS WHERE I ADD

    btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try{
                sqLiteHelper.insertData(
                        edtName.getText().toString().trim(),
                        edtPrice.getText().toString().trim(),
                        imageViewToByte(imageView)
                );
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                   
                finish();
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    });

}

private byte[] imageViewToByte(ImageView image) {
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    return byteArray;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY){
        if(grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You don't have permission to access file location!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return;
    }

    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void init(){
    edtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtName);
    edtPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPrice);
    btnChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChoose);
    btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
    btnList = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnList);
    imageView = (CircularImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
}

}
```

Comment: from where you have fetching images?

Comment: @AniruddhParihar from the gallery

Comment: then why you are passing  byte[] foodImage in adapter, simple pass the URI of image and set in ImageView.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of the lag during scroll you have to load images efficiently. The best you can do is to use an image loading library like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

Just import the library and replace these lines

```
byte[] foodImage = food.getImage();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(foodImage, 0, foodImage.length);
holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

with this one

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(food.getImage())
    .into(holder.imageView);
```

I also suggest you read the [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html)

**EDIT**

In order to avoid the recycling issue (which in fact it's not an issue, it's the way a listview works) you have to check for each item if it has a photo or not.

If yes then load the image using Glide, else set to null (or a default image of your choice).

```
if (food.getImage() != null && food.getImage().length > 0) {
        Glide.with(context)
                .load(food.getImage())
                .into(holder.imageView);
    }
    else {
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(null); //or an image of your choice
    }
```

Comment: Ok the scroll is smooth now, but the same image gets called in all cardViews?

Comment: You get same images in more than one cardViews, right? Do all food items have photo or not?

Comment: Yes I have images in more than one cardViews and no not all of them have images.

Comment: It is still not working, I added the activity where I add to sqlite in edit above. The problem I'm having is the image I choose the first time is shown in all new cardViews.

Comment: can you please look at my FoodList Activity, I get the image with cursor.getBlog (3). I don't know if my problem could perhaps be there?

Comment: Yes, it is very likely. Have you tried to debug your code?

Answer (score 0):

**try this one**
this example will help you alot

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

     private Context mContext;
     ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();

     public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
      mContext = c; 
     }

     void add(String path){
      itemList.add(path); 
     }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
   return itemList.size();
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return null;
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   ImageView imageView;
         if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
             imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
             imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(220, 220));
             imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
             imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
         } else {
             imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
         }

         Bitmap bm = decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(itemList.get(position), 220, 220);

         imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
         return imageView;
  }

  public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

   Bitmap bm = null;
   // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
   final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
   options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
   BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

   // Calculate inSampleSize
   options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

   // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
   options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
   bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options); 

   return bm;   
  }

  public int calculateInSampleSize(

   BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
   // Raw height and width of image
   final int height = options.outHeight;
   final int width = options.outWidth;
   int inSampleSize = 1;

   if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
    if (width > height) {
     inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);    
    } else {
     inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);    
    }   
   }

   return inSampleSize;    
  }

 }

    ImageAdapter myImageAdapter;

 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        myImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        gridview.setAdapter(myImageAdapter);

        String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment
          .getExternalStorageDirectory()
          .getAbsolutePath();

        String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/test/";

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), targetPath, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        File targetDirector = new File(targetPath);

        File[] files = targetDirector.listFiles();
        for (File file : files){
         myImageAdapter.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
        } 
    }

}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/44344691/edit) your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Comment: here you can see in onCreate() its listing all images from specific path and adding these images in Adapter's itemList , so for images you can applt same it will not lags your images.